# Linear transformation with respect to basis problem

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Let $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $T(\begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\2 \end{bmatrix}$ and $T(\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\1 \end{bmatrix}$. Find the matrix $A$ representing $T$.

I understand that to approach this problem, I have to view $\begin{bmatrix} 3 \\1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ as a basis, $B = \{ v_1, v_2 \}$, where $[v1 v2]$ is the transition matrix from $[x]B$ to $x$. How do I use $\begin{bmatrix} 1\\2 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\1 \end{bmatrix}$? I'm unclear on their connection to the basis vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$.

Comment: Hint: matrix multiplication can be thought of as taking linear combinations of columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative to the bases $B$ and the standard basis,  the matrix is:. $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\2&1\end{pmatrix}$.

The change of basis matrix is: $\begin{pmatrix}3&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$.

The latter changes basis from $B$ to the standard basis.

Thus you want: $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\2&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}3&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}^{-1}$.

I will leave this calculation for you.

> $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\2&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-1&4\\-1&5\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\2&1\end{pmatrix}$ does here - how does it relate back to the basis?

Comment: It's, as I said, the matrix relative to the given nonstandard basis $B$ and the standard basis for $\Bbb R^2$.  There's a cute trick to seeing it: apply it to the elements of $B$, which, in terms of $B$ are just $e_1$ and $e_2$, and you will get the columns.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin {bmatrix} 1\\0 \end{bmatrix} =  - \begin {bmatrix} -1\\0 \end{bmatrix}$

$T(\begin {bmatrix} 1\\0 \end{bmatrix} ) = -T(\begin {bmatrix} -1\\0 \end{bmatrix}) = -\begin {bmatrix} 1\\1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin {bmatrix} -1\\-1 \end{bmatrix}$

$\begin {bmatrix} 0\\1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin {bmatrix} 3\\1 \end{bmatrix} + 3\begin {bmatrix} -1\\0 \end{bmatrix}$

$T(\begin {bmatrix} 1\\0 \end{bmatrix} ) = T(\begin {bmatrix} 3\\1 \end{bmatrix}) + 3T(\begin {bmatrix} -1\\0 \end{bmatrix}) = \begin {bmatrix} 1\\2 \end{bmatrix} + 3\begin {bmatrix} 1\\1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin {bmatrix} 4\\5 \end{bmatrix}$

$T = \begin {bmatrix} -1&4\\-1&5 \end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 0):

Let T be the transformation represented by $\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c&d\end{pmatrix}$

Now, we are given that 
$$T([3,1]) = [1,2], T([-1, 0]) = [1,1]$$

Applyin the transformation for the first equation

$$\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c&d\end{pmatrix}.\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix}$$

This will give you two equations in $a,b,c,d$. Similarly, you will get two equations from the other equation. Can you proceed?

This is not the simplest way of solving it, but is the most basic. Other techniques are all based on this. Faster methods are available, but I suggest going through this exercise at least once

Answer (score 0):

Let $\alpha$ be the standard ordered basis for $\mathbb R^2$ and $\beta = \{(3,1),(-1,0)\}$. Then we have
$$\begin{align} [\textsf{T}]_\alpha 
&= [\textsf{T} \circ \operatorname{id}]_\alpha \\
&= [\textsf{T}]_\beta^\alpha [\operatorname{id}]_\alpha^\beta \\
&= [\textsf{T}]_\beta^\alpha ([\operatorname{id}]_\beta^\alpha)^{-1}.
\end{align}$$
Now, $[\textsf{T}]_\beta^\alpha$ is already given and $[\operatorname{id}]_\beta^\alpha$ is just the matrix whose columns are the vectors of $\beta$.